# how to use MVC6 Dependency Injection methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have a translation service and I need to expose a property that I want to use across my application.

```
services.AddScoped<IMyTranslator, MyTranslator>();
```

I use services.AddScoped to register this interface and its implementation. When I set a breakpoint to the constructor of MyTranslator, I can see that this class is initialized all the time.

I could not use  AddSingleton, because it's shared across all sessions. I can not change the language for one user base on another user has changed language once.
I need a method that will initialize my middleware once per session.

Comment: As things stand the question you have asked is unclear and is a candidate for closure. What is your problem, what is it you are having problems with or trying to achieve? When you say initialized all the time do you mean the class is initialized every time the interface is used within the request? Can you show us the code you have used to register the service?

Comment: To produce a question that can be answered by the community pose a question in clear language describing the problem and what you would like to achieve, as well as anything you have already tried or researched. Where possible include a minimally reproducing code example. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

The `services.AddScoped` is already scoped to the user request, each time a user request reaches the server, an instance is created to serve this specific request only and it is not shard with other users.

Comment: Yes ,I know. My middleware doesn't need to be created again, I can still use the same instance that was create the first time. Is there any method call services.AddSingleSession something like that

Comment: I don't understand, you need to use the middleware per session but at the same time you don't want it created for every request !

Comment: No,  AddScoped works right now, but the instance is always the same, then it's not necessary to create it every time isn't it?  I have a property on my middleware called current language, I cannot use AddSingleton. I need something in between.

Comment: Can you show us the declaration for your middleware property in question?

Comment: `public interface IMyTranslationStore
    {       
        TranslationDataShared TranslationData { get; set; }
    }`      It is a service that handles the language state, event and database behind to store and retrieve data

Comment: If your `IMyTranslationStore ` is created for every request, then `TranslationData` should be as well